# I need an SQL query that selects from either Column A or B depending on the existence of a string in Column C

Tags: mysql, sql

I need an SQL query that selects from Column A if Column C contains the string 'ebook'. Otherwise, select from Column B.

So something like:

```
 IF (Table.ColumnC = "ebook") SELECT Table.ColumnA AS Publisher
ELSE SELECT Table.ColumnB AS Publisher
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select 
  case when columnC = 'e-book' 
    then columnA 
    else columnB 
  end as Publisher
from myTable;
```

You need a case statement

I reformatted to help show how this works.

Basically Case is a scalar (row per row) IF statement

There can be multiple conditions `WHEN`, similar to `else if`.  The function goes from condition to condition, if no conditions are passed, the `ELSE` value is used.

There are simple and search forms of CASE [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Simple CASE expression:

```
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Searched CASE expression:

```
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Comment: Are both these answers correct? This one looks much more like English.

Comment: They both work perfectly.  It's just a style difference

Comment: The syntax diagram you showed is not for the form of `CASE` that you used. You don't have a `case-expression`.

Comment: Hey was just editing.  There are two forms: simple and search case statements.  Mine is search, which I find more intuitive.  @scaisEdge has a simple CASE statement

Answer (score 3):

```
select case columnC when 'ebook' then columnA  else columnB end as publisher 
from my_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you can write it like this:

```
SELECT IF(Table.ColumnC = 'ebook', Table.ColumnA, Table.ColumnB) AS Publisher FROM Table...
```

If you have more than one possibility, then go for `CASE..WHEN..THEN..ELSE..END`.